# Who has the right to close questions?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Seems to me that some people are abusing close votes on interesting questions, even if those questions are getting answers from people.

So I would like to know, who has the right to close these questions?

Comment: Unfortunately the OP doesn't have an account on meta so won't get to see these excellent answers.

Comment: It's this account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/142178/rebol-tutorial

Comment: And this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332976/why-would-you-learn-another-programming-language-closed

Comment: Yes, I'm really angry, it was a genuine question, I read all the answers and would like to get more.

Someone even complains he was answering the question was closed.

Comment: @Rebol - you'll need to contact team@stackoverflow.com to get this question associated with your meta account.

Comment: Some people abuse it and interpret the rules in a very narrow way, which goes against the idea to make the website more inclusive like the rest of society. This leads to some sites having very different enforcement standards and rules, which leads to a bad experience. Here, you can see someone abusing the system and coming up with his own interpretation of the rules, against the consensus. He's also promoting his own site, which has laxer rules. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/224640/how-would-ancient-people-claim-back-the-desert-using-magic?noredirect=1#comment690831_224640

Answer (score 7):

As others mentioned, any user with 3000 rep can vote to close a question, with 5 votes resulting in a close.  Once the question is closed, any user with 3000 rep can vote to re-open the question.  5 votes that direction and it's open again.  Users can only vote to open or close a question once, but other than that this can continue indefinitely.

Additionally, moderators can permanently close a question, at their own discretion.  Moderators are not repuation based, but rather chosen by a community vote.  The permanent close option replaces the normal vote-to-close system for moderators (as a meta-moderator, I can't 'vote' to close a question.  I can only close it or leave it alone), and so we are sometimes reluctant to cast that vote without some community push first.

In your case specifically, no moderator was involved in the closing of your question.

Comment: I've often thought that moderator close votes should be reversible by voting. Moderator delete votes should be final.

Comment: Well, moderators have the option of locking, which can either keep a post open, closed, or deleted by disallowing intervention from ordinary users. It's left up to the mods to determine when and where this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who has at least 3000 reputation can vote to close questions (see: https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Also, this question will probably be closed/moved as it belongs on meta.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who has 3000+ rep can vote to close a question.
Once five people to close it's closed, and then people can vote to reopen it (with the samee constraints: 3000+ rep and five voters).