# Are Moderators noted?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who have the right to close questions ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17937/who-have-the-right-to-close-questions)

People who get points because of their questions and answers doesn't mean they are good moderators.

Some people seem to hate questions when it relates to something new as if they fear for their language, it seems they are very akeen to close such question whereas they're getting answer.

They don't close jokes whereas they close questions such as "Why would you learn a new programming language".

Comment: Is there a question here?  It seems more like a rant against some unnamed moderator who seems to have different opinions from your own.

Comment: This is when I wish for a "Close as WTF" option.

Comment: Adam: this probably ties in with his previous posts about having his dupes closed by the community, so now he is ranting about how just because someone has 3,000 points they don't make good judges.

Comment: The questions you asked, that got closed, didn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Moderators are listed in the /about page on every site, and meta in particular lists the mods for all sites: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 3):

As you were informed here:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17932/why-was-my-question-closed-while-others-similar-were-not

Your question is not valid. Please read the FAQ and discontinue this nonsense.

Comment: If my question is not valid, if people answer it means it's valid no ? Or are we in a Bureaucracy here ?

Comment: @rebol: No, that does not mean it was valid. Nor does the existence of votes or any other question.

Comment: People answer, because they want points.

Comment: There is no easier way to get rep than to answer a stupid, off topic post.

Answer (score 0):

Wait... What now? You aren't making any sense, Rebol. I've seen joke questions closed on numerous occasions, while questions regarding new languages or libraries tend to do reasonably well.

Link to examples of what you're talking about, or *it didn't happen*.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17937/who-have-the-right-to-close-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17932/why-was-my-question-closed-while-others-similar-were-not

Comment: @Brandon: huh... Well, that's crap. He posted a GTKY question and wonders why it got closed?

Comment: Every time I see "GTKY" all I can imagine it standing for is "Get The KY".

Comment: Example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332976/why-would-you-learn-another-programming-language

It's the first time I complain about a question being closed. Because I'm really angry, I was interested by all the answers, a lot of people were answering so why close it ?

Comment: @Rebol: i'd take the time to explain, but it's easier just to link to this old writeup again: http://everything2.com/title/Getting+to+Know+You
Read it, think about it, then come back and read the SO FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Rebol: Because it is not a valid question for the site. Try and read the FAQ and then listen to what we are telling you.

Comment: Yes I read the FAQ it says:
"of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere"

I got 18 answers for the question so it means it interested others no ?

Comment: Read *the rest* of the FAQ. And that other thing i linked to. Seriously, it'll help.

Comment: If you don't, Rich B's just gonna clutch his chest, wave the FAQ in the air, and start quoting from it street-preacher style.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't think it is going to help here.

Comment: FAQ says:
"No question is too trivial or too "newbie". Oh yes, and it should be about programming. You know, with a computer."
"questions that can be answered"

Mine can be answered so what's the problem ?

Comment: @Rebol: You are about the 50000th person to come crying when their off topic question was closed. All of them have gotten the rules explained to them and have been sent away. Here is your chance to decide whether you want to go away and be a productive user who asks good questions, or if you want to hold a grudge and make a mess of the site by posting these kinds of questions.

Comment: Are you Overzealot maybe ? You fear what about my questions ?

Comment: @Rebol: It cannot be answered. Technical questions need to have a right answer. Your question is too subjective to have a correct answer. I know you don't understand this and your emotions are raging on this, but no one is going to reverse this for you. You are simply wrong.

Comment: @Rebol: ok, i'll bite: what's the answer to your question? It certainly got enough replies, if it can be answered surely you should know the answer by now...

Comment: @Rebol: Stop this persecution complex. You are only giving everyone a more negative impression of you and hurting your argument.

Comment: The rules are for ALL including MODERATORS: you do not respect the RULES yourself !

Comment: I HAVE A DREAM that one day little white boys and girls and little black boys and girls will all be able to read the FAQ and learn to ask questions intelligently and not whine when their question is closed or downvoted. Yeah, I went there.

Comment: @Shog9 no statistically speaking it's not enough. For a sample of binary question Normal Law needs at least 30 answers.

Comment: @Rebol: You are correct. This is all a big abusive conspiracy because we do not like your avatar. Please take it up with the owners of the site: team@stackoverflow.com They will surely give you justice against all of us abusive mods.

Comment: @btk: Now we can only hope you meet the same demise.

Comment: *At least* thirty? There's no real answer, is there...

Comment: @Shog9: I know I am amazed, this is a new breed of whiner.