# Is the automatic election of moderators flawed in Stackoverflow?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Moderators noted ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17947/are-moderators-noted)

Moderators should be moderate as the name implies. They are automatically designated as soon as they reach 3000 points by an automated system. It is as if we had a super computer ruling for electing our politicians.

So my question is should this automatic election be supervised by some real humans ?

Comment: Voting to close as dupe of 17947.

Comment: If you need to rant for a while, go ahead. Just confine it to one question from now on and be warned that: 1) your rant is not unique: we have been over this several times before _and_ 2) We have users who are sick of it and will rant right back at you.

Comment: Technically, a moderator is one who reaches 10k points not 3k.

Comment: "Moderators should be moderate as the name implies" - the premise is off here.  Modertors shouldn't 'be' moderate, they should 'do' moderate, or simply 'moderate'(verb) - To lessen the violence, severity, or extremeness of (http://www.answers.com/topic/moderate)

Answer (score 13):

3000+ Rep users are not moderators, there are more like Junior-Janitors. They can not close questions - they can only vote to have it closed, and you need 5 people in total. Real Moderators on the other hand can close and even delete questions on their own.

While there were and still are some Edit/Close Wars, overall I think the system works very well by giving people that have put some effort into the site some powers that allow them to do more, without being able to nuke the whole place.

Is there anything specific that you find problematic about the powers of 3000+ Rep Users?

Comment: Yeah, they keep closing his questions. Therefore the system has to be flawed.

Comment: Tss tss I talk about one question that is LEGITIMATE WHICH GOT 18 ANSWERS there was no reason to close it except OVERZEALOTRY.

Comment: *Question. This is all about one lame question, and he is going to spam MSO until a mod steps in.

Comment: If it was valid, we wouldn't be having this discussion...

Comment: Well, he can always contact the team if he thinks people are abusive (some people indeed really are), that what the penalty box is for: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: Does this question do any harm ? "Why would you learn a new programming language" so why ? Oh maybe because it costs a few global warming for the Environnement hahaha !

Comment: @Rebol: Sumbitch, you're one of those dudes? This doesn't end well for you, I promise.

Comment: @Rebol, as easy as it was for 5 users to close your question, its just as easy for 5 users to reopen it. Let the community decide what happens. No need to continue making topics about it.

Comment: @Rebol: Once again, your nastiness is not going to help your case. Did you email team@stackoverflow.com like I recommended? What was the resolution?

Comment: @Rebol: I have no idea which question that is, but if it's closed then that means that FIVE people agreed that it should be closed, and that USUALLY means that the question was indeed somehow inappropriate for the site. There are always exceptions and sometimes five people can be wrong, but as said, that happens extremely rarely compared to the amount of questions.

Comment: "closed as subjective and argumentative" <~~~ I can't agree more.

Answer (score 3):

Moderators are not automatically elected. Please, *please* [read the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) - it is explained there, really...

Comment: Yeah, but his question wasn't closed by moderators. He's read *some* of the FAQ, but he needs to get as far as page #3 to understand this...

Comment: I love page three.  It's the one with the naked ladies!